# Android Search View always gives the same result

Tags: android, searchview

I am using search view in my app to search through a list of item and run a query on a URL.

I am using the following code :

```
public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
        mSearchView.setQuery("", false);
        mSearchView.clearFocus();
        mSearchView.setIconified(true);
        url+="intitle="+s+"&site=stackoverflow";
//        mSearchView.setQuery("", false);
//        mSearchView.clearFocus();
//        mSearchView.setIconified(true);
        new JSONTask().execute();
        return false;
    }
```

So I modify the URL based on the search query and run the async task to load the list of results.

This works fine the first time I search, but all subsequent searches give the same result even when the query is changed.

How do I fix this ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the variable `url` is global, you should set it's value to the initial value at the end of your `onQueryTextSubmit(String s)` method, because then on every next step it will concat the strings ( `+=` ) and will be something like this url = %your original value%intitle="s"&site=stackoverflowintitle="s"&site=stackoverflowintitle="s"&site=stackoverflow